# Solr : Getting Collations from a query response

Tags: solr, spell-checking, collation

Im trying to configure SOLR spell checking. My request and response seem to be working fine. Only problem is how do i get the Collations from the response.

This is the part of my response that has the collations.
What methods in the API do i use to extract the 3 collations.

```
 <str name="collation">ipod tough</str>
 <str name="collation">ipad tough</str>
 <str name="collation">wood tough</str>
 <str name="collation">food tough</str>
```

This is the method that im using currently:

```
List<String> suggestedTermsList = new ArrayList<String>();
if(aQueryResponse == null) {
  return suggestedTermsList;
}

try {
  SpellCheckResponse spellCheckResponse = aQueryResponse.getSpellCheckResponse();
  if(spellCheckResponse == null) {
    throw new Exception("No SpellCheckResponse in QueryResponse");
  }  

 List<Collation> collationList = spellCheckResponse.getCollatedResults();

  for(Collation c : collationList){
    suggestedTermsList.add(c.getCollationQueryString());
  }

}catch(Exception e) {
  Trace.Log("SolrSpellCheck",Trace.HIGH, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
}
return suggestedTermsList;
```

My response header is like so:

spellcheck={suggestions={ipood={numFound=5,startOffset=0,endOffset=5,suggestion=[ipod, ipad, wood, food, pod]},collation=ipod tough,collation=ipad tough,collation=wood tough,collation=food tough}}}

I get 4 collations which I want to add to a List suggestedTermsList which I then return to the calling code. Right now my ArrayList has 4 collations but it only has the last collation repeated 4 times. i.e food tough  - four times.

Comment: You don't say what client API you are using, or how you are reading the response.  Are you using SolrJ?

Comment: Hi Mike, Please have a look at my updated question.

Comment: Hmm that seems weird.  I haven't heard of a bug like that.  Are you sure you aren't reporting them incorrectly in an outer layer you have't shown us here?

Comment: I ended up adding spellcheck.collateExtendedResults = true and it returned the proper collations. I got help from the lucene forums. http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/SpellCheck-Print-Multiple-Collations-td3358391.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to call QueryResponse.getSpellCheckResponse() and go from there.  Here are some links to documentation you might find helpful:

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/response/SpellCheckResponse.Collation.html

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/index.html?org/apache/solr/client/solrj/response/SpellCheckResponse.html